# Animating a picture

Tags: animation, texturing, image, video

I am new to Blender. I have a simple picture (png) which I would like to apply a texture to.
But the texture should be applied in a slow rate, and only to parts of the picture along a line or curve.
Then I want to capture that animation somehow as a video or something?
Sorry if this sounds like a silly question.
For example if I have a picture of the number 1 in green. I want to apply a red texture to that 1 from top to bottom along a line, slowly so that it's color changes from green to red. I want to capture this animation somehow. Hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a video as a texture, or if you use cycles you can use a mix node and keyframe the fac value (picture needed).